# Как предусмотреть все символы из таблиц кодировок

Tags: java

Задача: Банкоматы допускают 4 или 6-значные ПИН-коды, а ПИН-коды не могут содержать ничего, кроме 4 цифр или 6 цифр.
    Если функции передана правильная строка PIN, верните true, иначе верните false.

Проблема: Нам подаются разные символы, например пробел или вот такой 9¾. Я предусмотрел в коде варианты по ASCII таблицы, а вот откуда другие символы появляются для теста не совсем понимаю. Знаю, что есть другие таблицы кодировок, но как тогда можно все варианты предусмотреть?

Код:

```
public static boolean validatePin(String pin) {
    char[] chArray = pin.toCharArray();
        for (char a = 1; a <= 47; a++) {
            for (char b = 58; b < 128; b++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < chArray.length; i++) {
                if (chArray[i] == a || chArray[i] == b) {
                    return false;
                }
                }
            }
            }

        if (chArray.length == 4 || chArray.length == 6) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
  }
```

Comment: А зачем такая сложная проверка? Может проще каждый символ  ПИН проверить, что он является цифрой, и тогда вернуть истину, а если хоть один не является - то ложь? И циклов меньше, и логика прозе, и проверок меньше. И вообще: зачем Вам проверять равенство?  может проще проверить д *chArray[i] <=47 && chArray >= 58* и тогда вернуть ложь?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, маленькая поправочка `(chArray[i] <= 47 || chArray[i] >= 58)` Нужно, чтобы условие было "||", а не "&&".

Comment: да конечно :)) сорри, поспешил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("^\\d+$").matcher(pin).find()
```

**UPD:** Что означают символы:

- начало строки: **^**
- конец строки: **$**
- цифровой символ: **\d**
- повторяется один или более раз: **+**

Подробнее о регулярных выражениях можно прочитать, например, [здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-v-java)

Comment: Спасибо, тоже отличный ответ. Можете подсказать, что означают символы внутри скобок. Понимаю, что регулярное выражение, просто интересно более подробно.

Comment: @Blacit обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Конечный код, с помощью комментария получилось уменьшить.

```
public static boolean validatePin(String pin) {
    char[] chArray = pin.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chArray.length; i++) {
                if (chArray[i] <= 47 || chArray[i] >= 58) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        if (chArray.length == 4 || chArray.length == 6) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
  }
```